# "to be applied to" vs "to be applied"

Tags: prepositions, passive-voice, relative-clauses

I'm German and I'm reading the English language General Relativity lecture notes by my professor, who is also German. As I read I take notes and corrections to help him improve the notes whenever I find errors.
I don't want to correct him where he's actually right and I'm not entirely sure if this is a mistake or not (emphasis mine):

> A 2-form in ℝ³ can be interpreted as as a space-filling staggering of parallel bars. **The two vectors to which the 2-form is applied form a area element** (the green parallelogram in the figure). The number of bars enclosed by this area element is the result value of the 2-form.

Apart from the obvious typos, shouldn't it be

> […] The two vectors to which the 2-form is applied **to** form an area element […]

I am asking if I need to add a preposition after the verb apply when it's used in a passive voice, where a "to" has already been added to the object in a relative clause. (Forgive me if that's not what I'm asking, High School English grammar has been a while)

As a clarification of terminology for people not familiar with this kind of mathematical lingo, one usually says "We apply 2-form α to vector **u**".

Comment: You've already *got* the one-and-only preposition required, in ***to** which*. Which you *could* validly have relocated after the main verb ***applied***, even though this would then be immediately followed by the very same word acting as an infinitive marker for the verb ***to form*** - that's to say it's not necessarily a problem to have multiple instances of homophonous ***two, 2, to*** performing different roles in the noun phrase *The two vectors which the 2-form is applied **to** to form an area element.* If it's not a noun phrase, just drop the infinitive marker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the short version of the main phrase

> The two vectors form an area element (the parallelogram).

When you add the descriptive phrase, the *passive verb,* 'is applied,' has its *object,* 'which,' and the *preposition,* 'to,' just as you expected.

> The two vectors [to which the 2-form is applied] form an area element.

An extra 'to' would be a *hypercorrection.* This is discussed [here](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004493.html), in Language Log, under the title "A phenomenon in which I'm starting to believe in."